# Moodle form not showing when I make moodle header footer hidden

Tags: php, moodle

I have `moodle` page like the following with a form inside it:

```
<?php

require_once('../../config.php');

global $DB;

global $COURSE;

$courseid = $COURSE->id;

if (!$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid))) {

    print_error('invalidcourse', 'block_eparticipation', $courseid);

}



require_login($course);

$PAGE->set_url('/blocks/eparticipation/view.php', array('id' => $courseid));

$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');

echo $OUTPUT->header();

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/epoll_form.php');

  $pollform = new mform("poll_action.php?val={$valid}");

  $pollform->display();

echo $OUTPUT->footer(); 

?>
```

**I need to hide the header and footer** so I did as follows:

```
echo "<div style='display:none;'>";

echo $OUTPUT->header();

echo "</div>";

.............................

echo "<div style='display:none;'>";

echo $OUTPUT->footer();

echo "</div>";
```

Or we can use : `hide_header();`
But When I did this my form also get hidden.  I am getting a blank page.

**I want to hide the header and footer only with my form not hidden**.

Is there any alternatives to hide moodle header and footer?Please guide me.

**Moodle Version : 2.9**

Comment: Is there something preventing you from simply removing `echo $OUTPUT->header();`? Does it include scripts/styles you still require?

Comment: Are you sure that `hide_header` function is defined? Maybe you should write it by yourself?

Comment: @TomWalters I do not want header and footer. So did as above. I have form in my page as you can see $pollform. When I doing so that form also get hidden. I am not using scripts or styles here. using moodle standard style and validations.

Comment: @u_mulder `hide_header()` is defined moodle 1.5+ version. I am using `moodle 2.9`

Comment: Then why not just remove `$OUTPUT->header();`?

Comment: @TomWalters if I remove that then I am not getting the moodle features such as editor, moodle form and so on!!

Comment: So in actual fact the functions are loading scripts and styles. It sounds like you need to read up on [the output API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_API) and specifically [custom renderers](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_renderers).

Comment: @TomWalters read that never makes any difference!!

Answer (score 1):

Call:

```
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('popup');
```

Before you call echo $OUTPUT->header(). This will hide the header and the page blocks.

You must call echo $OUTPUT->header() on every Moodle page, as that includes the HTML head tag, with all the required CSS, javascript, etc needed by Moodle (as well as the visible 'header' elements).

See: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API for full details of the $PAGE variable.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I am trying to redirect from the moodle page to a simple php page which will not have moodle header. Between the redirection it shows a **continue** page. It looks weired.

Comment: Is this a separate question you are asking? The continue page shows if you put a timeout in the redirect, or if there was some sort of output (including errors) before the redirect function was called.

Comment: I am not giving any timeout, simply redirecting from one page to other form a moodle page and it is showing continue. It looks messy thats why I am trying to hide header footer. Any other alternative also welcome!!